# Alignment not working on one machine, but working on others?

Tags: microsoft-windows, align

Alignment is not working for me on my Windows machine, but it is on my Centos machine.  I want to understand why.

I first noticed the problem when I turned on `linum-mode`.  Here's what it looks like in Centos:

[image]

But in Windows, it looks like this:

[image]

Then, I tried to follow [Understanding of emacs align-regexp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/understanding-of-emacs-align-regexp), and the following is what I got.  In Centos:

[image]

But in Windows:

[image]

What is wrong with my alignment in Windows?  How can I fix it?

Comment: In a GUI version of Emacs, there is no reason (in my opinion) to use the fringe and the `|` symbol for line-numbers -- choose one or the other (my preference is just the fringe, and set the width accordingly).  There is recent activity in this forum regarding right alignment of line-numbers -- there are existing threads on that issue.  To the right of the left-fringe, you haven't shown us whether you are using tabs, or spaces, or some other method of alignment (e.g., stretch-glyph/overlay).  So, we'd all just be guessing as to what is between the various columns in the picture.

Comment: @lawlist But when I turn off the linum mode, I still get wrong align in the fourth picture. Also, all the text begin with no space or tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your screenshots, you are using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) in centos, but a [proportional/variable-width font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion) in Windows.

I haven't looked at the source code, but I suspect that the alignment functions are based on the number of characters in the line and *not* the width of each, individual character.  As such, they will line up visually with no problems when you use a monospaced font (because the width is constant), but in general, we would *not* expect them to line up visually with a variable-width font.

Setting your default font on your Windows machine to use a monospaced font should take care of the visual alignment problems.

Comment: You are right. 

`(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 115 :family "Consolas")`  After I add this, it solved. Thank you for your information.